# MailCore2 A stable connection to the server could not be established IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, gmail-imap

I've just tried to fetch gmail messages in a basic way, but it returns me with an error of 'A stable connection to the server could not be established' - is that any wrong with username and password? I've given my email mail-id and password to test below example.

```
MCOIMAPSession *session = [[MCOIMAPSession alloc] init];
[session setHostname:@"imap.gmail.com"];
[session setPort:993];
[session setUsername:@"..."];
[session setPassword:@"..."];
[session setConnectionType:MCOConnectionTypeTLS];

MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind requestKind = MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaders;
NSString *folder = @"INBOX";
MCOIndexSet *uids = [MCOIndexSet indexSetWithRange:MCORangeMake(1, UINT64_MAX)];

MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation *fetchOperation = [session fetchMessagesOperationWithFolder:folder requestKind:requestKind uids:uids];

[fetchOperation start:^(NSError * error, NSArray * fetchedMessages, MCOIndexSet * vanishedMessages) {
    //We've finished downloading the messages!

    //Let's check if there was an error:
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Error downloading message headers:%@", error);
    }

    //And, let's print out the messages...
    NSLog(@"The post man delivereth:%@", fetchedMessages);
}];
```

Comment: Sorry folks, I went deep on this problem and got a solution. The problem was not in my code it was on my gmail account through which I was trying to access mails. That account was having a 2-way secure authentication on privacy setting, So there is 'App password' account owner have to set to login on any app. if owner don't want to set 'App password' and want to go through regular password on apps, then he/she have to off 2-way secure notification off, then this code works fine with normal password.

Comment: Hey did anyone find solution... I am getting this error occasionally.. I really want to know the reason for the error

Comment: Hi @MalavSoni.. Where you able to find a solution to this. I face this same issue occasionally. Could not figure out the root cause.